# Accessing instance variables within a Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, parameter-passing

*This question has been rewritten because the way I originally wrote it was unclear.*

How do I take the values within `@form_params` and pass them to `get '/show_results'`?

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  configure :development do
    register Sinatra::Reloader
  end

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  post '/form_handler' do
    @form_params = params
    redirect to("/show_results/?#{@form_params}")
  end

  get '/show_results' do
    erb :display_result
  end
end
```

### index.erb

```
<form method="POST" action="/form_handler">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="first" value="John">
    <input type="hidden" name="middle" value="Q">
    <input type="hidden" name="last" value="Public">
    ...
</form>
```

### params (result)

{first => "John", middle => "Q", last => "Public"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the @form_params is a hash in your code. sth like that: 
`{"first" => "John", "middle" => "Q", "last" => "Public"}`. 
actually it's a string but can be converted into hash. 
when you apend it to the redirect url, it becomes,

```
/show_results?{"first" => "John", "middle" => "Q", "last" => "Public"}
```

and it is different from your expectation. as i guess you want something like that 0

```
/show_results?first=john&middle=Q ...
```

what you should do is,

take params and parse it. maybe sinatra has a built in method for this (better look documentation) but this can aslo easily be done with plain ruby.

```
post '/form_handler' do
  redirect_url = '/show_results'
  params.each { |k,v| redirect_url += "?#{k}=#{v}" } 
  #don't worry about above line, the rest of ?-s will be converted into &
  redirect to(redirect_url)
end
```

apart from all these, why are you sending post request then redirect it to a get block?

if you submit your form with get, it will automatically will be parsed to

```
url?k1=v1&k2=v2 ..
```

i mean this.

**index.erb**

```
<form method="get" action="/form_handler">
    <input type="text" name="first" value="John">
    <input type="text" name="middle" value="Q">
    <input type="text" name="last" value="Public">
    <input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

main file.

```
get '/' do 
  erb :index
end

get '/form_handler' do 
  erb :display_result
end
```

then in your display_result file, or inside get block, you can easily access the params[:first], params[:middle] and use them.

Comment: thank you for your answer. In response to your question, the reason I am sending post request then redirecting it to a get block is because I was finding that the post block wouldn't display `erb :display_result`. In this particular example, I know it is unnecessary to redirect to the get block, but as I made various attempts at making it work I realized I couldn't figure out how to send data to a get block.

Comment: simply use the last 2 snippets i've added. thus, you'll not need any custom logic to parse the params

Comment: you are my hero. That officially got me un-stuck. Thank you for the help!

Comment: nice to help you -))

Answer (score 1):

The `params` object is per-request. When you redirect, unless you explicitly pass them with the url they will be lost. By the way, you can use `sessions`, which passes data as a cookie but can be configured to use a database instead.

Here's an option if you `require 'active_support/all'`

```
redirect to("/show_name?#{my_hash.to_param}"):
```

In ActiveSupport (bundled with Rails, not Sinatra) the Hash#to_param method works like this:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
hash.to_param
# => "a=1&b=2"
```

If you have learned about the components of a URL, you will know that query params can be passed after the `?` in a url, which is how `"/show_name?#{my_hash.to_param}"` works.

It's nice that this method also works with hash and array params, which use a special syntax in the url, i.e. `/path?my_list[]=1&my_list[]=2` makes `param[:my_list] == ['1','2']`.

Except that in some circumstances the `&` `[` `]` characters need to be escaped (replaced with special character sequences).

```
puts ({a: 1, b: [1,2]}.to_param)
# => a=1B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2

URI.unescape CGI.unescape({a: 1, b: [1,2,3]}.to_param)
# => "a=1&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3"
```

Comment: I have rewritten my question to make more sense. maxple's response was drafted in response to my original question. So, if his response doesn't match the question then its not his fault.